# How can i have a mediaPlayer in android to play 2 or more mp3 files one after one?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm creating an android application that I want it to plays multiple mp3 files one after one.

I've got an mediaPlayer  on my app, how do I set a queue to play mp3 files?

Answer (score 5):

Way to achieve this is to create a class that implements OnCompletionListener which handles the onCompletion and receives the next file to play. 
First define your Class to PlayMedia like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class PlayMedia extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = PlayMedia.class.getSimpleName();

    Context context;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int[] soundIDs;
    int idx =1;

    public PlayMedia(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        this.mediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
    }
    public PlayMedia(final Context context, final int[] soundIDs) {
        this.context = context;
        this.soundIDs=soundIDs;
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,soundIDs[0]);
        setNextMediaForMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
    }

    public void setNextMediaForMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer player){
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {         
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if(soundIDs.length>idx){
                    mp.release();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context,soundIDs[idx]);
                    setNextMediaForMediaPlayer(mp);
                    mp.start();
                    idx+=1;
                }               
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "", e);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "", e);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "", e);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then use PlayMedia like this:

```
int[] soundIDs = {R.raw.firstmp3, R.raw.secondmp3};
PlayMedia playAudio = new PlayMedia(context,soundIDs);
playAudio.execute();
```

Comment: Happy to know that it helped you. Can you please accept this answer and up vote for it.

Comment: This works, but what if you don't want the lag from ```MediaPlayer.create(context,soundIDs[idx]);```?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a LinkedList and a complementary ListIterator to manage a queue of MediaPlayers.

For each mp3 files that you know should be in the queue, call the ListIterator's `add()` method with a media player created with`MediaPlayer.create();`

Be warned that you need to be very careful about where the iterator position is while managing the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I added a que which I'm using as a FIFO:

companion object {
val playList: MutableList =
Collections.synchronizedList(mutableListOf())
}

I have a function that initializes media player if necessary, then adds the mri file to the que.  After queing the file, I call a start function that exits is the player is playing and starts the next file otherwise.  I configured mediaPlayer with an OnCompletionListener which starts the next file if the que isn't empty.  It's simple and hasn't given me any problems.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
private void PlaySoundNv(int soundId){
    if(mediaPlayer ==null || !mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,soundId);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                if (!qSoundID.isEmpty()){

                    PlaySoundNv(qSoundID.poll());
                }

            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }else{
        qSoundID.add(soundId);
    }

}
```